# Xcopy error: invalid number of parameters

Tags: cmd, xcopy

I am trying to copy files from E:/bin/Debug/ to E:/New using `xcopy`. My syntax is

```
xcopy /s "E:\bin\Debug*.*E:\New"
```

on windows 10.

It returns

> error invalid number of parameter

or sometimes

> New not foundinvalid path

. Please help me to find my mistake. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a space between the arguments, and each parameter needs to be in quotes*.

```
E:\> xcopy /s /i "E:\bin\Debug\*.*" "E:\New\"
E:\bin\Debug\Test\InnerDir\FileA.txt
E:\bin\Debug\Test\InnerDir\FileB.txt
2 files copied
```

By default xcopy does not create the target directory if it does not exist. Use the `/i` option if that is what you want. xcopy documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy).

> /i:
>   If Source is a directory or contains wildcards and Destination does not exist, xcopy assumes Destination specifies a directory name and creates a new directory. Then, xcopy copies all specified files into the new directory. By default, xcopy prompts you to specify whether Destination is a file or a directory.

Alternatively you can use mkdir to create 'E:\New\'

Quotemarks*: Only needed when your arguments contain spaces, such as Directory names like `Program Files`, which have spaces. But it's a good idea to always include them.

Comment: I am in E: drive in command prompt i followed above command and now error is Cannot perform a cyclic copy.

Comment: This did not work for me at all, not entirely sure if its because I have DFS pathing

Comment: @user310602 that means you are trying to copy in such a way that the destination is within the source directory folder. This would result in an endless loop.